# how do you make an average of a table whose data is from the database to display in crystal reports and VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I want to make an average in the crystal report, by displaying the average of the input data, how can I do it?
average in IPK

I've tried using the formula in the crystal report but I don't know what logic to do,
how can you make the average work, input the data from the database and the amount of data is uncertain, so how can the average formula be done

Answer (score 0):

What is IPK?

Place the column you wish to average in the detail section and select it with your mouse.  Click the sigma button in the toolbar (or use the menu option of ***Insert, Summary***).  Select 'Average' as the summary calculation:

[image]